# jQuery - selectors

Tags: jquery, html-table, css-selectors

How shall I bind onClick action to rows except clickable elements?

For example, I have such table:

```
...
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            something
        </td>
        <td>
           <a href="some_url.php">link</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
...
```

If I use such code: `$('tbody > tr').click(function(){ alert('clicked'); });` then when I click anything within row (including links) I will get my function executed. But I want it to be executed only if I clicked not on clickable element ("a href" in my example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take advantage of event bubbling:

```
$('tbody > tr').click(function(e) {
    /* do something */
});

$('tbody > tr a[href]').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

When clicking a link it will work as usual but prevent the click event from bubbling up to the `tr` so its click handler will not trigger in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could add a [`.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to the links themselves:

```
$('tbody > tr').click(function(){
    alert('clicked');
});
$('tbody > tr a').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation(); // Prevents the `click` to bubble to the tr handler
});
```

Basically, the `click` event will, per default, "bubble" (propagate) up the DOM tree. I.e., with only the `click` handler on `tbody > tr`, a click on the `tr` will result in `click` event for these elements (in this order):

1. The `tr`
2. The `tbody`
3. The `table`
4. ...
5. The `body`
6. (The `html`? - not sure)

Now, the `.stopPropagation()` call on the event *"Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event."* ([source](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)), thus binding a dedicated handler to the `a` elements will catch (and stop) the `click` event on `a` elements, but leave the `tr` handler as before (with the exception that a click on the `a` elements catches those `click` events that were handled by the `tr` handler before.)

Comment: @Chvanikoff Yeah, it looked pretty lame, I know :) I've elaborated on my answer to make up for the lack of (new) information from before.